# How to make request session object in grails

Tags: grails

I need to use session object like java which can use in whole application.I know in Java but how can i use in grails. I don't know.

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

too complicated:

```
assert null == session.someKey
session.someKey = someValue
assert someValue == session.someKey
```

`session` is accessible in `controllers`, 'taglibs`and`filters`

Answer (score 0):

`session` is directly available in `grails controllers`, you can use like

```
session.setAttribute("key", "value");
```

then anywhere you can get value by

```
session.getAttribute("key")
```

Comment: is it good way to use like grails means it is reliable or not

Comment: yes,i don't think there is any problem,we are accessing the same way as we use in spring.

Comment: any other thing in grails except this